# I'm attempting to install Catalina-Os-icons to my home folder in .icons folder, but it doesn't show up in Themes

Tags: desktop-environment, icons

I'm running the latest version of Linux Mint Cinnamon.

I've installed the WhiteSur theme, and created the plank dock, but I can't get the Home folder to recognize my icon set when I placed it inside my `.icons` folder.

My icon set is `Os-Catalina-icons`